boost asio async_receive won't receive anything
I'm implementing a C++ custom port scanner using raw sockets and I'm facing a problem in my class NetScanner::StartReceive. I traced down the problem to the async_receive method where it never actually receives a response from destination address being scanned. Here's the code:
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <istream>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <netinet/ip.h>

#include "NetScanner.hpp"
#include "NetUtils.hpp"
#include "../error_handler/ErrorHandler.hpp"

using std::placeholders::_1;
[...]
void NetScanner::HandleReceive(const boost::system::error_code &error, std::size_t len, ScanInfo scan_info, shared_buffer buffer, shared_timer timer) {
    // Checks if the receive operation was aborted due to a timeout.
    if (error == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
      if (timeout_port_.find(scan_info.port) == timeout_port_.end()) {
        StartReceive(scan_info, timer);
      } else {
        PopulatePortInfo(scan_info.port, port_status::FILTERED);
      }
      return;
    } else if (error) { // Checks if an error occurred during the receive operation.
      (error_handler_.*&error_handler::ErrorHandler::HandleError)(error.message());
      PopulatePortInfo(scan_info.port, port_status::ABORTED);
    } else { // Processes the received data.
      buffer->commit(len);
      utils::TCPHeader header;
      std::istream stream(&(*buffer));
      stream >> header;
      if (header.Syn() && header.Ack()) {
        port_info_[header.Source()] =  port_status::OPEN;
      } else if (header.Rst() && header.Ack()) {
        port_info_[header.Source()] = port_status::CLOSED;
      } else {
        StartReceive(scan_info, timer);
        return;
      }
    }
    timer->cancel();
  }

  void NetScanner::HandleScan(const boost::system::error_code &error, std::size_t len, ScanInfo scan_info, shared_buffer buffer) {
    if (error) {
      (error_handler_.*&error_handler::ErrorHandler::HandleError)(error.message());
    } else {
      shared_timer timer = std::make_shared<basic_timer>(io_context_);
      std::cout << "Starting timer.." << std::endl;
      StartTimer(timeout_miliseconds_, scan_info, timer);
      StartReceive(scan_info, timer);
    }
  }

  void NetScanner::StartReceive(ScanInfo scan_info, shared_timer timer) {
    auto &&buffer = std::make_shared<stream_buffer>();
    socket_.async_receive(
      buffer->prepare(buffer_size),
      std::bind(&NetScanner::HandleReceive, this, _1, _2, scan_info, buffer, timer)
    );
  }

  void NetScanner::StartTimer(int milliseconds, ScanInfo scan_info, shared_timer timer) {
    timer->expires_from_now(std::chrono::milliseconds(milliseconds));
    timer->async_wait(std::bind(&NetScanner::Timeout, this, _1, scan_info, timer));
  [...]

When I try to scan any port, it will return me as filtered (even though it is open) because it hits this line of code in the HandleReceive method.
    if (error == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
      if (timeout_port_.find(scan_info.port) == timeout_port_.end()) {

Meaning the async_receive got no buffer from the port being scanned back in the timeframe of the timeout value.
You can check the full code at https://github.com/alexbsec/parasyte/blob/master/src/network/NetScanner.cpp
I tried to increase the timeout, but even with large times the above if statement is still being triggered.
I attempted debugging it by showing what was in the buffer after the alleged async_receive and it is empty.
I also checked that the async_receive tries to receive the answer back for as long as the timeout is set, meaning the if statement above is only triggered after that.

(error_handler_.*&error_handler::ErrorHandler::HandleError)(error.message()); Really? Was this AI generated? error_handler_.HandleError(error.message()); seems a little more normal ¯\(ツ)/¯

Just to be on the safe side: you did see the response in your tcpdump or whatever you're using to debug your stuff, and it's just your code that doesn't receive it?

@ChristianStieber yes, from tcpdump I got the scanner sending an RST immediately after receiving a SYN-ACK. So technically the raw packets are being sent, just not received

@sehe ah yes, it does make more sense. But the error handler class is just a prototype for now. I plan to make it more readable and usable in the future xD. Ty for pointing that out!

I suggest compiling with warnings. It will point out many odd things, and also showed me lines like reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(&header_) which just seems both useless and wrong?

@sehe ok, should I manually serialize the struct into byte arrays instead of using reinterpret_cast? Somehow I need a way to calculate the checksums. I'm working on solving the warnings that are problematic here too, if I manage to solve the async_receive from here, I'll let you know.

That's not what I said. What I meant is something like this: https://github.com/sehe/parasyte/commit/05a0899694f243dc7d2a66a11db0c5bd7c25c2bc I have no clue what that weird reinterpret is supposed to do (it reinterprets the POINTER, not the header struct anyways). So I cannot comment on how to improve that

@sehe I'm using reinterpret_cast to convert a pointer to a header struct into a uint16_t* pointer to calculate its checksum. The checksum function requires an array of uint16_t as input, so I need to access the raw bytes of the struct in this format. Also, tysm for your commit. I'm checking it here and seems better than the stuff I coded

Oh. My problems apparently has been that you have a dozen or so different [Calculate]Checksum functions lying around, and I thought the pointer was implicitly used as uin32_t - I might check later when I have time. Do look at the rest, because it was my point. The compiler is trying to tell you things.

@sehe thanks. If you ever feel like contributing more I'd be much appreciated! I'm putting a lot of effort in this project and looking for collabs :)

@J.Buschinelli I like what you did with breaking up the commits. I have spent more time then I like to admit trying to get a clang-format close enough to the existing style. I think it would help contributions if it was included: https://github.com/sehe/parasyte/tree/clang-format

Please show a [mre]. At a guess there's nothing running your io_context

@AlanBirtles I'm struggling to make a minimal reproducible example. Everything is intertwined in such a way that writing this is as hard as finding the root cause. The io_context is being run and I actually get this in the tcpdump output:
In  IP 192.168.0.157.10273 > 127.0.0.1.5555: Flags [S], seq 988903578, win 4096, length 0 19:59:48.114260 lo    In  IP 127.0.0.1.5555 > 192.168.0.157.10273: Flags [S.], seq 4170600839, ack 988903579, win 33280, options [mss 65495], length 0 19:59:48.114264 lo    In  IP 192.168.0.157.10273 > 127.0.0.1.5555: Flags [R], seq 988903579, win 0, length 0

@AlanBirtles, in this tcpdump output, I was scanning an open port on my local machine. It shows that everything runs okay until the point of receiving the SYN-ACK packet back. What happens during the execution of the scanner is that the timeout reaches its limit and marks the port as filtered because it never actually parses the SYN-ACK packet from the async_receive. It seems that async_receive is not capturing this, and the first if statement in HandleReceive is triggered.
